# Борзая и гончая: одно и то же или нет?

Tags: омонимы

Борзый или борзой — это, как я понимаю, быстрый, резвый (борзый конь). Гончий — практически то же самое, тот, кто гонит кого-то. То есть, одно и то же или нет "борзая собака", "гончая собака"?
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Гончая - это собака, которая выгоняет дичь на охотника, или приводит охотника к дичи, идя по следу.

Борзая - собака для безружейной охоты (травли).

Гончая лаем идёт по следу дичи, а борзая эту дичь догоняет и ловит. Сейчас с борзыми почти не охотятся, но раньше это было одно из любимых развлечений дворянства, и борзые ценились очень высоко.

Comment: Маленькое уточнение. 
Любая гончая собака - в общем-то достаточно универсальна, но основное назначение гончих - гон, т.е. прямое преследование дичи, в т.ч. раненой (бладхантеров). Нагон на охотника - уже специализация отдельных пород.  
Работа же по следу без непосредственного преследования больше свойственна легавым.   

И еще. Борзые породы были достаточно многообразны по качествам и назначению. Сейчас, увы, стали больше декоративными.